# HP Envy x360 Ryzen 5 : 17.10 not booting

Tags: xorg, hp, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

My computer is an HP Envy x360 Convertible AMD Ryzen 5.
Didn't research the issues with installing Linux until I had bought it.

Managed to overcome the UEFI to install 16.04 initially. The screen was in 800x600 mode with no wifi, but at least it was ‘working’.  Invested in a usb-c to RSJ adapter, connected to ethernet. At some point (because I’ve been struggling with this for weeks now) I recall I installed AMDGPU_PRO and had proper screen resolution but couldn’t log in. Bad password was detected as such, but good password just looped back to login screen.  Then I upgraded to 17.10. Now Ubuntu fails to boot to login screen, with amongst other error messages;

```
acer_wmi : Unsupported machine has AMWO_GUIDI, unable to load
```

and

```
ACPI error : method parse/execution failed\_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170531/psparse-550)
```

at which point it hangs.

I've read around and think it's a video driver issue, so following advice to use the boot options (‘e’) and adding 'nomodeset', it then fails by telling me that initrd is too big

Going from recovery mode into the command line the Linux partition is then readonly, so I can’t create a mountpoint for a usb to copy error log files.

Finally managed to grab them from the windows side of things using DiskInternals LinuxReader:

Here would be the output of `/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log` if AskUbuntu system stopped telling me that it looks like spam.

I read on the FOSS site that 17.10 uses Wayland by default, so a bit of a surprise the errors relate to Xorg.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might make progress?

PS I haven’t used windows for many years; I’m surprised at how good it is now (Fall Creator).

Answer (score 1):

I just read on fedoraforum that both Ubuntu 18.04 and Fedora 28 boot and run nicely, although the touchscreen is not working. kernel 4.17 is scheduled for mid-June release, so you could get most functionality now and everything working in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to hear this but kernel 4.17 is when they expect the gpu to be fully functional. Install Ubuntu 18.04 for now everything but touchscreen will work. But if you use anything that requires hardware acceleration, it will crash at some point. Whether it be 20 minutes or 2 hours. Oh and don't bother with amdgpu-pro. It's the same thing that's in the kernel. It just has other stuff like opencl and vulkan support which you can get from repos. Don't forget to set amdgpu.dc=1

Comment: Thanks Zach. So, no point trying other Linux ‘flavours’ either then. Well, at least I know, and that hopefully at some future point there will be a way forward for me. For now I’ll stick with M$ on the HP (I have Linux on other machines).

Comment: Update: Using Kernel 4.17.5 now and even have wifi!